# Java Spring User authorization check

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

There is a configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
public static final String JWT_TOKEN_HEADER_PARAM = "X-Authorization";
public static final String FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT = "/api/auth/login";
public static final String TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT = "/api/**";
public static final String TOKEN_REFRESH_ENTRY_POINT = "/api/auth/token";
public static final String TEMPLATE_DOWNLOAD = "/templateDownload";

@Autowired
private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
@Autowired
private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;
@Autowired
private AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler;
@Autowired
private AjaxAuthenticationProvider ajaxAuthenticationProvider;
@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;

@Autowired
private NoteAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;
 

@Autowired
private TokenExtractor tokenExtractor;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

protected AjaxLoginProcessingFilter buildAjaxLoginProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
    AjaxLoginProcessingFilter filter = new AjaxLoginProcessingFilter(FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT, successHandler,
            failureHandler, objectMapper);
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
    return filter;
}

protected JwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter buildJwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
    List<String> pathsToSkip = Arrays.asList(TOKEN_REFRESH_ENTRY_POINT, FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT);
    SkipPathRequestMatcher matcher = new SkipPathRequestMatcher(pathsToSkip, TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT);
    JwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new JwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(failureHandler,
            tokenExtractor, matcher);
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
    return filter;
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(ajaxAuthenticationProvider);
    auth.authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable() // We don't need CSRF for JWT based authentication
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(this.authenticationEntryPoint)

            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll() // Login
                                                                                                // end-point
            .antMatchers(TOKEN_REFRESH_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll() // Token
                                                                // refresh
                                                                // end-point
            .antMatchers(TEMPLATE_DOWNLOAD).permitAll() // Download the note
                                                        // template does not
                                                        // require
                                                        // authentication
            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT).authenticated() // Protected
                                                                                                    // API
                                                                                                    // End-points
            .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).clearAuthentication(true)
            .invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .and().addFilterBefore(buildAjaxLoginProcessingFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(buildJwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

}

}
```

In a method that is available to everyone: authorized and unauthorized users, you need to separate the logic for those who are authorized and not. Well, for example - display the name if authorized, and if not - Just "Hello".

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/testApi/getName", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getName() {
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String userName;
    if (principal instanceof UserContext) {
        userName = ((UserContext) principal).getUsername();
    } else {
        try {
            userName = principal.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            userName = "Error";
        }
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userName, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Now defines all users as anonymousUser
[This is the request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOkFU.png)

Comment: Is `getName` API a part of `TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT`?

Comment: @aksappy no. getname has a different address. / testapi / getname

Comment: Okay, I suspect it is not being filtered to include security context, can you update the URI and test this once again please?

Comment: @aksappy You probably did not understand the question. I need that the method can be called by both unauthorized and authorized. But in the method itself, you need to find out which of them is authorized. Seis this method is available to everyone - but all users are anonymousUser

Comment: Okay so for that we need to first allow `getName` to be filtered through the authentication filter, with anonymous || hasLoggedIn . Otherwise, the security context won't get set.

Comment: My level in java is Low. I'm just starting to learn. And it’s not clear to me what exactly needs to be done so that the / api / * address would be requests only for authorized ones. And for example / forall / * was available to everyone. But so that in the methods by the last address it would be possible to identify users if it is authorized.

Comment: Alright. Let me try something and post an answer instead of lengthy comments.